# Agrupar views no SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou com um pequeno bloqueio de raciocínio lógico. Eu tenho uma tabela (tabela1) organizada dessa maneira, mas precisaria retornar a consulta como a tabela2 logo abaixo. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

[image: TABELA 1]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pesquise por PIVOT http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/sql/principais-caracteristicas-database-2108383-ptb.html e CASE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query

Answer (score 0):

O que você procura é transformar linhas em colunas, que pode ser atingido através do [PIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/sql/principais-caracteristicas-database-2108383-ptb.html)

Fiz um exemplo para você atingir o seu objetivo:

```
create table teste (
  codigo number, 
  nome varchar2(50),
  uso varchar2(10),  
  arquivo varchar2(50), 
  tipo varchar2(50)
);
insert into teste values (10, 'Joao', 'SIM', 'C:JOAO/REALT', 'REALT');

insert into teste values (10, 'Joao', 'SIM', 'C:JOAO/BOLET', 'BOLET');

insert into teste values (10, 'Joao', 'SIM', 'C:JOAO/CHAM', 'CHAM');
```

Query final:

```
select * from teste
pivot (
       max(arquivo)
       for tipo in ('REALT'  as REAT,
                    'CHAM'   as CHAM,
                    'BOLET'  as BOLET
      ));
```

[image: Pivot Oracle]

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT PQ.CODIGO, PQ.NOME, PQ.USO, 
DECODE(PA.TIPO, 'REALT', PA.ARQUIVO) AS REALT, 
DECODE(PA.TIPO, 'BOLET', PA.ARQUIVO) AS BOLET, 
DECODE(PA.TIPO, 'CHAM', PA.ARQUIVO) AS CHAM FROM PQ, PA;
```