# SQL - Select com possível concatenação

Tags: sql, select, concatenação-de-string

Criei uma consulta que faz uma concatenação dos meus resultados. É uma tabela com nomes e a qual faixa (quadrado) elas estão classificadas. A tabela se chama *consulta_prontidao* e os campos são *nome* e *quadrado*:

```
Select Main.Quadrado,
   Left(Main.Nome,Len(Main.Nome)-1) As "Nome"
From
(
    Select distinct ST2.Quadrado, 
        (
            Select ST1.Nome + ','
            From dbo.Consulta_Prontidao ST1
            Where ST1.Quadrado = ST2.Quadrado
            AND ST1.codigoUnidade = 45
            AND ST1.codigoPeriodo = 5
            ORDER BY ST1.Quadrado
            For XML PATH ('')
        ) [Nome]
    From dbo.Consulta_Prontidao ST2
) [Main]
```

Sendo que eu tenho apenas a opção de 9 quadrados possíveis, a consulta vem assim, por exemplo:

> ```
> Quadrado | Nomes
> -------- | -----
> 1        | NULL
> 2        | Maria,Tamiris
> 3        | Kellen
> 4        | Elis
> 5        | Paulo,Alex
> 6        | Mauro,Rodrigo,Elaine,Gabriela
> 7        | NULL
> 8        | Teixeira,Luis
> 9        | NULL
> ```

Mas eu gostaria de fazer um pouco diferente: que houvessem nove colunas de resultado chamadas Quadrado 1, Quadrado 2, Quadrado 3, ... , Quadrado 9. A consulta SELECT viria só com uma linha assim, por exemplo:

> ```
> Quadrado 1 | Quadrado 2    | Quadrado 3 | Quadrado 4 | Quadrado 5 | Quadrado 6                    | Quadrado 7 | Quadrado 8     | Quadrado 9
> ---------- | ------------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------------------------- | ---------- | -------------- | ----------
> NULL       | Maria,Tamiris | Kellen     | Elis       | Paulo,Alex | Mauro,Rodrigo,Elaine,Gabriela | NULL       | Teixeira, Luis | NULL
> ```

Alguém tem ideia como eu posso fazer? Também é uma espécie de concatenação, eu acho. Mas não descobri o melhor modo ainda.

Comment: De maneira mais clara, deseja transformar linhas em colunas? Acho que tem algo sobre isso aqui no SO. Está usano MySQL?

Comment: isso se chama pivot, você pode dá uma olhada nesse link https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjx16TG49jRAhXCF5AKHT_RCkoQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devmedia.com.br%2Fpivot-no-sql-server-invertendo-linhas-e-colunas-em-um-exemplo-real%2F28318&usg=AFQjCNHgEUfsOkw_TNcpiiVUK5do79NqsQ&bvm=bv.144686652,d.Y2I&cad=rja

Comment: Pesquise por PIVOT e CASE , https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16 , mas vai precisar também de um STRING_AGG ... https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você queira transformar linhas em colunas. Já existem vários topicos que abordam o mesmo assunto. Veja um deles [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168963/agrupar-views-no-sql-oracle).

Fiz um exemplo utilizando oracle, que você pode usar como base para seu banco:

```
create table consulta_prontidao(nome VARCHAR(30), quadrado VARCHAR(30));


insert into consulta_prontidao values ('1', NULL);

insert into consulta_prontidao values ('2','Maria');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('2','Tamiris');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('3','Kellen');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('4','Elis');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('5','Paulo');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('5','Alex');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('6','Mauro');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('6','Rodrigo');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('6','Elaine');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('6','Gabriela');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('7', NULL);
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('8', 'Teixeira');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('8', 'Luis');
insert into consulta_prontidao values ('9', NULL);
```

Depois da tabela montada, basta fazer a concatenação de string (nesse caso, o [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm)) junto com o [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/sql/principais-caracteristicas-database-2108383-ptb.html)

```
select * from consulta_prontidao
pivot (
       LISTAGG(quadrado, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY quadrado)
       for nome in ('1'  as QUADRADO_1,
                    '2'  as QUADRADO_2,
                    '3'  as QUADRADO_3,
                    '4'  as QUADRADO_4,
                    '5'  as QUADRADO_5,
                    '6'  as QUADRADO_6,
                    '7'  as QUADRADO_7,
                    '8'  as QUADRADO_8,
                    '9'  as QUADRADO_9
      ));
```

Resultado

[image: Resultado da Query]

**EDIT:**

Aparentemente você trabalha com `MySql`, então sugiro a utilização do [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Ficando assim:

```
select * from consulta_prontidao
pivot (
       group_concat(quadrado ',')
       for nome in ('1'  as QUADRADO_1,
                    '2'  as QUADRADO_2,
                    '3'  as QUADRADO_3,
                    '4'  as QUADRADO_4,
                    '5'  as QUADRADO_5,
                    '6'  as QUADRADO_6,
                    '7'  as QUADRADO_7,
                    '8'  as QUADRADO_8,
                    '9'  as QUADRADO_9
      ));
```

Não tenho como testar nesse momento a implementação no MySql. Teste e avise se tiver problema que eu dou um jeito de corrigir.

Em `SqlServer` 2016 utilize [STRING_AGG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx):

```
select * from consulta_prontidao
pivot (
       STRING_AGG (quadrado, ',')
       for nome in ('1'  as QUADRADO_1,
                    '2'  as QUADRADO_2,
                    '3'  as QUADRADO_3,
                    '4'  as QUADRADO_4,
                    '5'  as QUADRADO_5,
                    '6'  as QUADRADO_6,
                    '7'  as QUADRADO_7,
                    '8'  as QUADRADO_8,
                    '9'  as QUADRADO_9
      ));
```

Comment: Não, eu trabalho com SQL Server nesse site. Não é MySQL.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo utilizando `SqlServer`